# how to convert output from alert box to display on page - javascript/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a script that counts specific words from `<td>`'s on my page and displays the total within an HTML element. In this example I am counting how many times the word "Complete" appears within tables. So the half-way-there script I have now is as follows:

```
<p>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         var x = $("td");
         alert($('td:contains("Complete")').length);
      });
   </script>
</p>
```

This works pretty well, when the page loads an alert box pops up and correctly counts the occurrences of the word "Complete." My hang up is how do I modify this to display on the page instead of with the alert box? I've tried using innerHTML [shown here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp) and analyzed a number of similar questions here on stack overflow trying to mimic the examples, but I always break the counting function when trying to adapt it over.

This is my first time writing js and here is my latest attempt which makes me feel like that dog who has no idea what he's doing:

```
<p class="completed">
   <script>
      $(document.getElementById("completed")).innerHTML(function(){
         var x = $("td");
         $('td:contains("Complete")').length;
      });
   </script>
</p>
```

Insights into how I can fix the second code block is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing jquery and vanilla javascript a bit too much.stick to one

Comment: Just go to your first piece of code and replace alert with $('#completed').html('stuff to input'); you also probably want to move your script at header or footer

Comment: if it's jsut a plain number, I'd use `text()` instead..

Comment: @Elentriel True. Thanks for pointing out, didn't even realize I was mix and matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply print the output where you want instead of to an alert box. Consider the following:

```
<p>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         var x = $("td");
         // Print out the result to the #resultsGoHere element
         $('#resultsGoHere').html($('td:contains("Complete")').length);
      });
   </script>
</p>
<p id="resultsGoHere"></p>
```

Comment: Good solution, thank you! As was pointing out earlier by another I was mixing libraries in my attempts (among other mistakes) so thanks for simplifying things.